# How to use passport-facebook for multi apps on the same service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I have set up my facebook login with passport-facebook like this

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(secrets.facebook, function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  if (req.user) {
    User.findOne({ facebook: profile.id }, function(err, existingUser) {
      if (existingUser) {
         ...bla bla
          user.save(function(err) {
            req.flash('info', { msg: 'Facebook account has been linked.' });
            done(err, user);
          });
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    User.findOne({ facebook: profile.id }, function(err, existingUser) {
      if (existingUser) return done(null, existingUser);
      User.findOne({ email: profile._json.email }, function(err, existingEmailUser) {
        if (existingEmailUser) {
       ...bla bla
          user.save(function(err) {
            done(err, user);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
}));
```

and my routes are like so :

```
 router.get(namespace + '/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email', 'user_location'] }));
    router.get(namespace + '/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), function(req, res) {
        res.json({})
    });
```

The thing is, I have more then one app running on this service and I want all of them to authenticate using facebook, but I want each one to query and save to a different db , meaning a different `User` model.

Can I pass it (the `User`) via the route call? Can I initiate several 'facebook logins' and use a different one for every app?